# HTTP ok STATUS axios on javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, cors

I am trying to make an intermediate api (B) to connect two applications (A, C), the problem is that I am a novice with axios and I am not achieving it.

From application A I make this call and in turn calls a service that performs the post.

```
   const updateLead = () => {
        pipelineServices.updateLeads(data.token, data.leads).then(resp => console.log(resp));
    }
```

```
    updateLeads(leads, token) {

        let config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: `http://localhost:3525/api/updateLead`,
            data: {leads, token},
        };
    
        let aux =  axios(config)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    console.log("OK");
                }
                if (response.status == 401) {
                    console.log("User is not authorized");
                }
                if (response.status == 400) {
                    console.log("Invalid data given. Details are available in the request response");
                }
            })
            .catch(async function (error) {
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(error)
            });
    
        return aux;
    
    }
```

the problem is that the browser in the LOG responds to me in the following way

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use "cors-anywhere" to proxy your connections. CORS Anywhere is a NodeJS reverse proxy which adds CORS headers to the proxied request.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable CORS in the application at `localhost:3525`. You can read about it here: https://enable-cors.org/